# How to store random integers into an instance of a class

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arrayobject

I am tasked to create **10 instances of the `Square` class within a for loop** using **10 random integer values (10 - 20)** as their length and store the 10 Square instances in `sqArray` and print out the length and area of all the elements in the array.

Here is my code for the square class

```
public class Square {

    private int length;

       // Create a constructor that takes in len as parameter
       public Square(int len){
            length = len;
       }

       public int getLength(){
            return length;
       }

       public double calculateArea(){
            return length * length; 
       }
} //Square
```

Here is my code for my main class

```
public class SquareUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create an instance of array sqArray.
        Square[] sqArray = new Square [10];

        for(int i = 0; i < sqArray.length; i++) {

            sqArray[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I didn't really do anything in my `main class` as I don't know what this question is talking about. I have 2 questions:

1. How do I generate a random integer in the for loop if the data type is an object?
2. What do they mean by "store the 10 Square instances in `sqArray`"? Are they asking me to store the random integers in the `sqArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just to generate random integer between 10 and 20 and set it to the created object like that :

```
public class SquareUser {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Create an instance of array sqArray.
            Square[] sqArray = new Square [10];

            for(int i = 0; i < sqArray.length; i++) {

                int val = 10 + (int) (Math.random()*10);
                sqArray[i] = new Square(val);
                System.out.println("Length is "+val);
                System.out.println("Area is "+sqArray[i].calculateArea());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

1. Replace

```
sqArray[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
```

With

```
sqArray[i] = new Square( 10 + Math.floor((int) (Math.random()*11)));
```

2. array of `Square` objects with exactly 10 elements